# how to use WHERE IN mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do I pass an array and use WHERE IN inside stored procedure?

Do i need to concatenate input string or something ?

Lets say

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `abc`.`table1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `abc`.`test`
(IN somestring VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM abc.table1 
    WHERE flight_type IN somestring
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the string concatenation and the PREPARE statement to run dynamically built queries.

`somestring` must be constructed in a valid SQL format like `'1','2','3'`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `abc`.`table1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `abc`.`test`
(IN somestring VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    @s=CONCAT("
    SELECT * FROM abc.table1 
    WHERE flight_type IN (",somestring,");")
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE @s;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` if `somestring` is formatted `a,b,c,d`:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc.table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(flight_type, somestring)
```

Comment: What about `FIND_IN_SET` optimization though? Does it use indexes?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer needed modification to work with my version of MariaDB.

The CONCAT statement was missing a semicolon, The EXECUTE statement was called on **@s** (a variable) rather than **stmt** (a statement), and the drop/create portion was confusing.  Here's my rewrite:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dbname`.`procedurename`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `dbname`.`procedurename`
(IN somestring VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @s=CONCAT("
    SELECT * FROM dbname.table1 
    WHERE flight_type IN (",somestring,");");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as `somestring` is of the form

```
"(item1, item2, item3, ... )"
```

if not, you could format it accordingly inside of your SP but I'm not sure what the best practice is.