# MySQL Using WHERE IN () in STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a many-to-many relationsship between two tables (events and collections).

I'm building a PHP application and want to create a Stored Procedure that takes one or more collection names and returns a table of events that are part of the collections.

**This works**

A test using hard coded collection names works but is obviously not what I'm after.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `test`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN `name` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN
    SELECT e.name, e.start, e.end, e.description, c.name AS collection FROM events AS e
    INNER JOIN events_collections AS ec
    ON e.id = ec.event_id
    INNER JOIN collections AS c
    ON c.id = ec.collection_id
    WHERE c.name IN ('Inventors', 'Philosophers');
END
```

**What I've tried**

I've searched around and found these:
[how to use WHERE IN mysql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373495/how-to-use-where-in-mysql-stored-procedure)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/working-with-where-in-in-a-mysql-stored-procedure

Which in my case would translate to the code below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `get_collection`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_collection`(IN `coll_name` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN

    SET @Query = CONCAT('SELECT e.name, e.start, e.end, e.description, c.name AS collection FROM events AS e
    INNER JOIN events_collections AS ec
    ON e.id = ec.event_id
    INNER JOIN collections AS c
    ON c.id = ec.collection_id
    WHERE c.name IN (',`coll_name`,')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

When calling the procedure...

```
CALL get_collection('Inventors, Philosophers')
```

...it returns an error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Inventors' in 'where clause'
```

I don't understand where this goes wrong and would really appreciate some input.

Comment: Look more closely at the answer to the first question you linked; at the use of quotes in the input string. For your example you would need to pass `"'Inventors', 'Philosophers'"` as `coll_name` i.e. `get_collection("'Inventors', 'Philosophers'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote string variables like:

```
CALL get_collection("'Inventors', 'Philosophers'");
```