# MYSQL Best way to parametrize variable values for IN clause in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have to write a stored procedure where I want to set values for a variable called colorId using IN operator, the parameter can be a list of integer ids or no ids. I am wondering what should be the type of variable in the stored procedure?

where color_id IN (1,2,3,4);

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use WHERE IN mysql stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373495/how-to-use-where-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: so I have integer values. if I do concatenate like '1,2,3,4' as a parameter value X let's assume, naive question, how would I remove the quotes, before adding X to In clause?                             ColorId IN (X)

Comment: The whole query will be a string, the concate of `'WHERE IN (' + '1, 2, 3, 4' + ')'` will provide `'WHERE IN (1, 2, 3, 4)'`

Answer (score 1):

If you send a string like `'1,2,3,4'` as a single parameter, the query will run as if you had done this:

```
where color_id IN ('1,2,3,4');
```

The way MySQL does implicit type casts to integer, this converts the value to an integer using only the leading digits, and ignores everything after the first comma. So it will really run as if you had done this:

```
where color_id IN (1);
```

There is no way to "remove" the quotes. The point of query parameters is that they are not combined with the query until after the SQL parsing is done. Therefore the parameter is fixed as a single string value in that expression. You can't convert a parameter into a list of discrete values, because that would change the syntax of the query.

So you must pass multiple parameters, one for each value in your list. Like this:

```
...where color_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

And use some function in your client application to split the string into multiple parameters and then pass them not as a single string value, but as multiple integer values.

Some people try to use tricks like using MySQL's FIND_IN_SET() function, but I don't recommend this, because it cannot be optimized with any index.

You tagged this question [stored-procedures](/questions/tagged/stored-procedures) from which I infer that you are trying to write a procedures that accepts a string of comma-separated integers and use it in an IN() predicate. This is more inconvenient to do in a stored procedure than in any other programming language, because MySQL's stored procedure language doesn't support arrays or good functions for splitting strings or counting elements. It can be done with enough effort, but the code is awful and you will quickly wish you were using any other language.

Answer (score 0):

Your can pass parameter value like this - '1,2,3,4' and [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)  function will be able to search in the provided string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM colors
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(color_id, param);  # param --> '1,2,3,4'
```